# If $x^2+y^2 <1$ and $4y>x^2$, then $2x^2 + (2y-1)^2 <1$

Tags: inequality

I'm trying to prove the following two inequalities:

1. If $x^2+y^2 >1$ and $4y>x^2$, then $2x^2 + (2y-1)^2 > 1$ .
2. If $x^2+y^2 <1$ and $4y>x^2$, then $2x^2 + (2y-1)^2 < 1$ .

Both $x$ and $y$ are real numbers. The first inequality can be shown as follows: $$2x^2+(2y-1)^2>2(1-y^2)+(2y-1)^2=2(y-1)^2+1 \geq 1$$ (The condition $4y > x^2$ is superfluous)

For the second inequality, I tried: $2x^2 + (2y-1)^2  =2x^2 + (4y^2 - 4y + 1) <x^2 + 4y^2 + 1  $ (using $-4y < -x^2$). However, this seems not so useful.

It can be proved by plotting graph of ellipses $2x^2 + (2y-1)^2 = r$ for parameter $r$, and calculate the values of $r$ for which graphs are touched.

[image]

I seek an another proof of the second inequality. In particular, 'algebraic'(anyway) methods are welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second statement is actually false. It can be seen from the graph – it is false in the region that is inside the circle, above the parabola and outside the ellipse. Concretely, $(x,y)=(0.8,0.4)$ violates the second statement.